# Modifying tables based on title (MapInfo)

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, tab

I have a query regarding the Mapbasic feature of MapInfo, I want to change the line style of an item depending on name (e.g if the .tab name contains the world group). I think I can work this out with a few bits of syntax help. So for example if I change one tab this appears in the MapBasic window

```
Set Window 376609128 Front
Set Map Window 376609128  Layer 10 Display Global    Global Line (2,2,16711680)    Arrows On
```

Would I need to write a statement similar to if contains "xx" then do that? I have a very basic knowledge of scripts syntax but is my basic understanding correct, would this be the way to do it?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: *word not world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alan

I assuming that you have a map with a number of layers and that you want to change the override style of certain layers if their name contains a certain text, correct?

You could build a loop like this:

```
Include "MapBasic.def"

Dim nMID, nLayer As Integer,
    sLayer As String

nMID = FrontWindow()
For nLayer = 1 To MapperInfo(nMID, MAPPER_INFO_LAYERS)
    sLayer = LayerInfo(nMID, nLayer, LAYER_INFO_NAME)
    If sLayer Like "%xx%" Then
        Set Map Window nMID
            Layer nLayer 
                Display Global Global Line (2,2,16711680)
                Arrows On
    ElseIf sLayer Like "%yy%" Then
        Set Map Window nMID
            Layer nLayer 
                Display Global Global Line (2,2,16711680)
                Arrows On
    '**add extra cases here below if you need to
    '**ElseIf sLayer Like "%zz%" Then
    '**    Set Map Window nMID
    '**        Layer nLayer 
    '**            Display Global Global Line (2,2,16711680)
    '**            Arrows On
    End if
Next
```

Above I test the name of the table against a certain condition. You could also use the name of the tab file of the layer by replacing

```
sLayer = LayerInfo(nMID, nLayer, LAYER_INFO_NAME)
```

with

```
sLayer = LayerInfo(nMID, nLayer, LAYER_INFO_PATH)
```

This is from the top of my head and I have not tested it, so it might need a bit tweaking.

Comment: Peter, I get the errors:

Variable nMID not defined and 
Loop control variable not defined

Comment: Never mind, got around that now, but when I come to run it in MapInfo I am getting:

Variable or Field MAPPER_INFO_LAYERS not defined

Comment: Alan, I have modified the answer to also have the line for including the file MapBasic.def. Sorry that I forgot that in my first response

Comment: Thank you! This has both sped up some aspects of my work, and impressed my boss!